# Responsive website menu z-index

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, z-index, concrete5

i'm trying to build a responsive menu. I'm having some problems with adding the correct Z-indexes.

Here is the website: http://erlendvanlandeghem.be/
When you make your window smaller, you should get a button that says "show menu". The menu then expands behind the content (cwrap). I've tried fixing it with z-indexes, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add this code in a jsfiddle? this makes it easy to edit.

Comment: Yes, try to rebuild the menu in a sandbox. It might help you to understand where is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code main.css at 302 number line.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
#navwrapper {
   width: 100%;
   left: -1px;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: transparent;
   max-width: 480px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, Shah Rukh already gave the solution. But i checked yours because better instructions for rookies like me

Answer (score 2):

just add `position:relative;` to the following id `#navwrapper`

Comment: Worked, i changed the postion of the navwrapper to relative in my @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {    part of the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add z-index to #navwrapper and it will work

```
#navwrapper {
  width: 240px;
  left: -1px;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 3px #888888;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: This makes the other content not selectable (for example on the page 'sculptures' , no more lightbox)